# Read <img> inside another element NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, rss, nsxmlparser

I'm using the NSXMLParser to parse RSS feed into my table view in my iPhone application. By using the `foundCharacter` method I'm able to parse everything inside the `description` element, including the `img` tag. I get the current element from the `didStartElement`and store it in `currentElement`. In `foundCharacters`:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    }
}
```

This reads the `img` tag as plain text so my question is how can I extract this tag? It doesn't seem like the `didStartElement` isn't called for the `img` tag.

**Edit**

Here is a part of the XML:

```
<item>
    <guid>
        http://computersweden.idg.se/2.33337/1.599059/sa-slipper-foretagen-ur-losenordstrasket
    </guid>
    <title>Så slipper företagen ur lösenordsträsket</title>
    <description>
        <img src="http://computersweden.idg.se/polopoly_fs/1.599059.1417423831!teaserImage/imageTypeSelector/localImage/336295786.jpg" border="0"><br>Säkerhetstänkandet hamnar lätt i en ond spiral. Intrång och läckor leder till säkerhetsåtgärder som användarna försöker hitta vägar runt . Följden blir nya intrång och spiralen fortsätter.
    </description>
```

Comment: Is that really the XML? Just like that other question I referenced above, the XML you provided in your question is not well formed. Because the `<`, and `&` are not encoded or included in `CDATA`, the XML parser is going to try to parse this HTML as XML (and will likely fail). Are you able to fix this XML? Many XML parsers will choke on this malformed XML.

Comment: Ok thank you, I guess I should go for another RSS feed... It's provided by a pretty big news paper in Sweden

Comment: Can you share the URL for the feed with us?

Comment: If you want, you can try parsing it with `NSXMLParser`. In the 'didStartElement` look for the element named `img` and then look at the `attributeDict` and your `src` might be there. (You can see the problem: from the parser's perspective, the HTML looks like malformed XML because there's no `CDATA`.)

Comment: By the way, I looked at the feeds at computersweden.idg.se (guessing from your provided XML that this is where you got it from), and they're properly encoding the `<`, `>`, and `&` of the `img` tags with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, respectively. If that's the case, then my previous comment does _not_ apply. Instead, you could use the regex I reference in my other question. When you provided that XML source that you included in your question, how did you get that? If you looked at that via a web browser or RSS reader, it can replace those codes. You need to look at the raw XML source.

Comment: Ah I see, when looking at the source I see those codes. Thank you very much!